# Is it possible for a TypeORM entity to pull from multiple tables?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

A new database has been added to our project to handle user authentication. I am working on linking the existing     `project_db.User`    table to the     `auth_db.Auth`     table. The goal is to pull     `User`     information such as `FirstName`, `LastName` from our new table.

I have been able to access the new db via raw SQL queries, but I then need to map the data out to create the     `User`    object for the front end. Ideally the     `User`    entity could be set up so it will point to the proper columns of the proper databases, so queries can be made in traditional TypeORM syntax.